# Full text search of posts I've viewed previously

Tags: feature-request, search

I found a question that I need a few days ago, and now I can't find it again through Google. I have to try to go to my Chrome history (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>) and then try to remember the title of the question.

I would like it if Stack Overflow showed me a history of all questions I've viewed and show a text box below it that would do simple text matching over all the answers/questions when I type stuff in there.

Comment: Have you tried including `site:stackoverflow.com` in the Google search query?

Comment: im only getting stackoverflow results but it was different questions.

Comment: Why don't you just use the site search? I really don't understand this feature request.

Comment: @CodyGray because it doesn't filter questions by whether I've seen them before or not. My frustration is that I remember I saw a question a few days ago that solves the problem I have now but I don't remember any specifics about it and what I'm googling now isn't bring up that question again.